# MonoDevelop Error synchronizing with XCode. IsDerivedFrom() must be from the same compilation

Tags: monodevelop

Ever since I upgraded to MonoDevelop 3.0 I am getting this

"Error synchronizing changes from XCode. IsDerivedFrom() must be from the same compilation"

After that I lose some of the Partial outlet declarations in the Designer classes and cant compile the project.

Here is the workflow:
1. Open my solution in MonoDevelop
2. Double-Click on the storyboard
3. Add a new TableViewController in XCode
4. Save, Quit XCode
5. MonoDevelop takes a minute synchronizing changes and throws the error. 
6. I revert code, lose my changes, and start all over again.

I am using an evaluation version of MonoTouch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug in MD 3.0](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5084). It has been fixed and the fix should be released soon.